# How to redirect the old URLs to new one (root->subdirectory)?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

There is a website on the domain root: `example.com`

Then I had to move it to `example.com/new`

What I want to do is to redirect all old URLs to new ones but not the root domain (example.com) itself. I mean if a visitor visits the example.com it shouldn't be redirect but if he visits a subpage such as example.com/login he should be redirected to the new URL (`example.com/new`).

**These are the examples:**

`example.com/login` -> `example.com/new/login`

`example.com/page/about` -> `example.com/new/page/about`

`example.com/page/about/contact` -> `example.com/new/page/about/contact`

**But** `example.com/new/something` shouldn't be redirect to `example.com/new/new/something`

**How can I do this with .htaccess file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just use `Redirect 301`:

```
Redirect 301 /login.html http://example.com/new/login.html
Redirect 301 /page/about.html http://example.com/new/page/about.html
```

These are ***permanent*** redirects. Make sure it is a perm and not temp redirect you want to do. If it was a temporary redirect, you would use `Redirect 302`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.